# Texture do not rotate with OpenGL (C)

Tags: c, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I am trying to rotate a texture extracted from a video frame (provided by ffmpeg), I have tried the following code :

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            textureWidth,
            textureHeight,
            GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            //s_pixels);
        pFrameConverted->data[0]);

glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.5,0.5,0.0);
glRotatef(90,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

//glDrawTexiOES(-dPaddingX, -dPaddingY, 0, drawWidth + 2 * dPaddingX, drawHeight + 2 * dPaddingY);
glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, drawWidth, drawHeight);
```

The image is not rotated, do you see the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From the [`GL_OES_draw_texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt) extension specification:

> Note also that s, t, r, and q are computed for each fragment as part of DrawTex rendering. This implies that the texture matrix is ignored and has no effect on the rendered result.

You are trying to transform the texture coordinates using the fixed-function texture matrix, but like point sprites, those coordinates are generated per-fragment rather than per-vertex. Thus, that means that nothing you do to the texture matrix is ever going to affect the output of `glDrawTexiOES (...)`.

Consider using a textured quad instead, those will pass through the traditional vertex processing pipeline.